# Shipping rate depending on the source and destination in magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping, import, csv, table-rates

I need to set special shipping cost for the transactions between hubs(Riyadh, Jeddah & Dammam). And  between Hubs and Substations too. I don't know how to write the csv file. Can anyone help?

[image: here i attach my existing csv file]

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Store > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Methods > Table Rates**

Select **Store View** as **Main website**

[image]

In **Table Rates** select **Condition** as **Price Vs. Destination**

Export Csv from there see in below image

[image]

Shipping calculated based on selected country, Region code and Post code and Order Subtotal.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply. bt i already have a csv file .that based on the weight & destination.

Comment: Fill it as show in above you just need to add product weight also in addition of above csv

Comment: ok. bt where should i enter the ship from ,ship to addresses?

Comment: There is no function ship from to ship to. It is calculated on destination only

Comment: so what should i do set shipping cost b/w the specified states?